# Xcode Local Commit Fails with "Multiple working copies failed to commit files." Error

Tags: xcode, commit

After updating to Xcode 10.1 when I select "Commit..." from Source Control I get the error

> Multiple working copies failed to commit files.

It had always worked before.

Pushing to Bitbucket still works. 
How can I get Commit to work again?

Answer (score 5):

Reason & solution:

Xcode bug, author details are deleted when Xcode is updated, the following from cmd line in workspace dir fixes the problem:

```
xcrun git config user.name "your_user_name"
xcrun git config user.email your_email
```

After running the commands, restart Xcode