# Xcode Failed to Commit Files: "Communication with the service was interrupted"

Tags: xcode, git, github, cocoapods, xcode12

[image: Screenshot]

I'm trying to commit ~9k files but I'm getting this error. I'm on Xcode 12.5.1.

There are some pods that I updated so lots of files were added and removed. Not sure if that is related to this issue.

[This did not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53346893/xcode-local-commit-fails-with-multiple-working-copies-failed-to-commit-files)

Answer (score 0):

Committing and pushing through the terminal worked. After though, there was one more file that showed up in source control (in Xcode) with "!" next to it. I was done after I committed that one. Maybe that was what was stopping Xcode. If that was the problem, Xcode should make it more clear.

I thought it had something to do with me having so many files. But I was able to commit a batch of like ~1k files in Xcode.